# Spring - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring

My method keeps returning a Null exception. I would like to retrieve some objects from the database.

The method in question

```
@Transactional
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public UserEntity getWithModules(Integer id){

    Criteria crit = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(UserEntity.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
    UserEntity userEntity = get(crit);

    //Retrieve the modules for the staff
    crit = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Module.class);

    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));

    crit.addOrder(Order.asc("moduleId"));
    Set<Module> sModule = new LinkedHashSet<Module>(crit.list());
    userEntity.setsModule(sModule);  

    return userEntity;
}
```

Controller for it

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/home/{id}", method = 

    RequestMethod.GET)  
    public String showStaffModules(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, ModelMap map, 

    HttpServletRequest request) {

           map.addAttribute("cp", request.getContextPath());

           map.addAttribute("Setter", userService.getWithModules(id));

           return "/home";
```

Stacktrace

```
     java.lang.NullPointerException
com.myproject.app.dao.UserDAO.getWithModules(UserDAO.java:59)
com.myproject.app.dao.UserDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$20f5ced0.invoke(<generated>)
org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
com.myproject.app.dao.UserDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a44426b2.getWithModules(<generated>)
com.myproject.app.service.UserServiceImpl.getWithModules(UserServiceImpl.java:58)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
$Proxy133.getWithModules(Unknown Source)
com.myproject.app.controller.UserController.getSetterPage(UserController.java:112)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Looking at the stack trace I checked on line 59 is from the method above, this code:

```
      userEntity.setsModule(sModule);
```

I would like to know why the objects cannot be retrieved.

Comment: `userEntity` is `null`.

Comment: Yes, I have checked now and it does return null. It should not really as the id is in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a `UserEntity` with the `id` that you specified, so `get(crit)` returns `null`.  When you try to invoke `userEntity.setsModule`, `userEntity` is `null`.

You need to check for `null` as returned by `get(crit)`.  This indicates that there was no match for your criteria.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. I did check and it does return null. The returned query says the id is null. I don't really know why as the user is in the database. Is there any way I can retrieve the details?

Comment: Is "id" the actual name of the field?  Case matters.  You might also want to check the state of the system to ensure that it is ready for queries, and is querying the same dataset that you expect it to.  You could also retrieve all entries without any restrictions, and sample some of the results to see if they are as you expect them to be.

Comment: Yes the id is the name of the field. I have listed all of the modules on page just to see if it was able to. And the dataset was as expected. I have also listed all of the users separately and can retrieve their details from the db. I just can't seem have a page open with a user id listing all of the children specific to that user.

Comment: @user2259555 Hmm... this sounds like you need to do some more debugging and write another question.  I don't have enough experience with the frameworks that you are using to help you in that area.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are doing on the get() method might be returning a null reference:

```
UserEntity userEntity = get(crit);
```

Comment: Yes that's correct. After adding a null check, the object was returning null.